# web.xml 404 redirect to servlet, how to get the original URI?

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I'm redirecting 404 errors to a servlet via the following in my web.xml.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/notFound.do</location>
</error-page>
```

I'd like to log where the request was trying to go, but I'm not getting it from the referrer header: request.getHeader("referer")

That shows 'null' if I just hit any old random non-existent page.

And request.getRequestURL()/request.getRequestURI() both merely shows the final landing servlet info (I.e., /notFound).

Any way to get the 'bad' page URL that was requested?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's available as a request attribute with the name `javax.servlet.forward.request_uri`, which is keyed by [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI). The error page location is namely invoked by a simple [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) call.

So, you can get it as follows in servlet:

```
String originalUri = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
```

or in EL:

```
<p>Original URI: ${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}</p>
```

Comment: It seems the servlet-api.jar (which provides javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher) in my Tomcat 7.0.19 install doesn't have any of those static fields; only the 'forward' and 'include' methods.  

But I can get it to work if I just put the string in directly.  E.g., the following works.
    request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's definitely present in there (click the links in my answer to see the javadocs). This problem suggests that you've configured your IDE to treat your project as a Servlet 2.4 project or older, or that you are relying your compiletime classpath on a loose and older versioned `servlet-api.jar` file which is placed elsewhere. Are you using Eclipse? If so, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706

Comment: Weird.  I popped open the servlet-api.jar and took a peek at the RequestDispatcher.class byte code, and I see  FORWARD_REQUEST_URI in there (as well as the other constants).  But opening the declaration within Eclipse only shows the two methods.  They're both pointed to the same jar on the disk...

Comment: As said, that can happen when your project is configured as servlet 2.4 project. Eclipse will then hide all newer classes/methods. In project's properties, check in the *Project facets* section if the *Dynamic Web Project* facet is set to 2.5 or preferably 3.0 (Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container). Also check if your `web.xml` is declared conform same servlet version.

Comment: Ah... my web.xml was at 2.4. Thanks so much!  BalusC, i'm looking for a way to contact you to get you something off your Amazon wish list.  Can you IM me?

eric555
@
jabber
dot
org