# Request url in custom 404 error page in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In Spring Boot 1.5.1 / SpringMVC with Thymeleaf I created a custom 404.html error page in /resources/templates/error/ If a user goes to a url that is not handled by any controller this 404.html page is shown.

I also noticed that I can display the timestamp, status (404) and error (Not Found) by doing:

```
<ol>
   <li>Timestamp: <p th:text="${timestamp}">timestamp</p></li>
   <li>Status: <p th:text="${status}">status</p></li>
   <li>Error: <p th:text="${error}">error</p></li>
</ol>
```

How can I display the requested (invalid) URL that led to the 404 error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465906/web-xml-404-redirect-to-servlet-how-to-get-the-original-uri

and why spring-batch is in set of tags?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota That should have been spring-boot, sorry.

Comment: @user1583209 use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692781/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-404-to-a-single-page-app