# How Do I Catch And Redirect URLs Outside Angular?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, gruntjs

I am trying to redirect invalid urls with the following

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  $stateProvider
    .state('test',{
      url:'/test',
      templateUrl: 'views/test.html'
    })
    .state('login',{
      url:'/login',
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
    });
  }).
```

This url gets redirected http://localhost/#/random but this doesn't http://localhost/random and I get

```
Cannot GET /random
```

I think it is because it is outside of angular (no hash #).

How do I catch people typing in random urls and redirect them appropriately?

I don't want to use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` for browser support issues.

I am using grunt serve for local front-end development and packaging and running with spring boot in production.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `http://localhost/random` in your address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you send a GET request to your **server**. AngularJS executes in the **browser**. So it's completely irrelevant.

Your server needs to do what you want (i.e. redirect to `/#/login`), instead of sending a 404.

Comment: How do I do that server redirect though? I added details of the servers running locally and in production.

Answer (score 0):

You either wan't to redirect to a specific route or page server side. So you need to intercept/override your methods that handle page errors and specifically target the 404.

Really you want to post this under a spring tag.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692781/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-404-to-a-single-page-app?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help you