# whitelabel error page 404 spring boot angular 6

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am using angular 6 with spring boot. i copied 'dist' file to spring boot project. and project running properly. but when i refresh the browser, it said 'white label error'. how i prevent from white label error.

working url
[image]

error page (when refresh)
[image]

Comment: Use the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692781/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-404-to-a-single-page-app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {useHash: true}),` useHash As true

https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy should help you understand.

Comment: currently my route file with 
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

Comment: yes use this` [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]` instead of this `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`

Comment: do i need to do changes in index.html ??
'base href ' ?

Comment: from your URL understanding you don't need to make any changes in base href but what is your deployed config

Comment: Happy to help @user1177842

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. I used the same configuration  [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]. but even after that issue persists.

Comment: still facing the same issue?

Comment: After setting this configuration, I am able to navigate but only with '#' before every root route. When I use navigation through the link button then it is not working.

Comment: @PeterS. are you using router? or just providing by URL?