# Not able to create custom error for Spring jersey application

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

We have a web based application with Front end in Angular JS 1 and REST service with Spring jersey frame work.We are using Spring 3.We have deployed our project in Tomcat 9.We have deployed angular js part as a separate project and REST service is build as a war file and deployed separately.

Suppose our application url is https://10.100.200.300:8443/DEMO.When we are trying to access the URL with a wrong value say https://10.100.200.300:8443/DEMO_TEST we are getting the error 404 i.e. resource not found by the tomcat server.We want to show some customized error page for 404 or any other tomcat error. Please suggest how to do it?

Comment: We are not using spring boot. we are using spring jersey.Our application web.xml is using the below entry com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet as a sevlet class

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here - [Configure spring boot to redirect 404 to a single page app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692781/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-404-to-a-single-page-app)

Make spring configuration as mentioned in above answer and reroute it to your desired page.

Comment: We are not using spring boot. we are using spring jersey.Our application web.xml is using the below entry com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet as a sevlet class