# Spring Boot Override Wildcard RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildcard, url-shortener, request-mapping

I am building a URL Shorter app (like Bitly). It is an SPA using Spring Boot & ReactJS. All web content is served off of `index.html`. All other routes are presumed to be `shortLink` redirect requests which should trigger a `clickShortUrl()` function to fetch the corresponding `originalLink` and redirect the user to that web address.

Therefore, I want the following routes to redirect to `index.html`:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/dashboard"})
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
```

and all other/unknown routes to trigger a wildcard function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{shortUrl}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object clickShortUrl(@PathVariable("shortUrl") String shortUrl, @RequestBody ClickDTO request) { 
    // internalLogicHere 
};
```

Individually, the mappings and functions are working. But combined, the `/{shortUrl}` wildcard route always takes precedence. I've googled around looking for ways to override this behavior. It seems to be possible a few ways, but all of my attempts have failed.

I read several posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692781/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-404-to-a-single-page-app) suggesting to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and override `addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)` to define view controllers for specific routes. I don't really understand this.  Is this the right path?  If so, can someone help me understand what `ViewControllerRegistry` is all about and set me on the right path?

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Redirecting and forwarding aren't the same thing. (2) Why are you "redirecting" to `index.html` instead of simply rendering it? (3) You _probably_ want to specify `produces = TEXT_HTML_VALUE` on your HTML mapping rather than trying to just separate API and UI by path.

Comment: React builds to `/resources/static`, so my understanding is that Spring Boot will automatically make these files available at their respective paths (e.g., `resources/static/test/me.html` would be available at `:8080/test/me.html`).  So all I really need to figure out is how to stop that wildcard route from overriding access to HTML files in `resources/static`.

Comment: Limit the wildcard to `produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`.

Comment: I tried that. It just throws `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported`

Comment: EDIT: Ignore that ^. I accidentally set to `consumes`, which of course would throw a consumption error in the browser. After changing to `produces` I still hit the wildcard route even when I target the more specific `/home`, `/dashboard`/ or root `/` paths.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Ended up using RegEx in the wildcard route to exclude the static paths used on the front end.

```
/** Redirect all '/' and '/dashboard/ requests to index.html. */
@GetMapping(value = {"path:/", "path:/dashboard"})
public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/index.html";
}
```

and the fallback route:

```
/**
 * Treat all routes as /{shortUrl} clicks except: '/', '/index.html, '/dashboard''
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "{_:^(?!index\\.html|dashboard).*$}")
public Object clickShortUrl(@PathVariable("shortUrl") String shortUrl, @RequestBody ClickDTO request) { 

    // internalLogicHere;
}
```