# HttpServletRequest getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER) returns NULL

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to get in logs the URI which triggered the [NOT FOUND 404] error.
I use ***.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER)*** and i'm getting null. The same i tried to use ***getRequestURL()*** and i'm getting the path of @RequestMapping method "/error".

**For example:**
If a user enters: mywebsite.com/fdsfihdif and there is no such address, i should see this in logs like this ***[NOT FOUND 404] User [john@yahoo.com] tried to access this URI : [mywebsite.com/fdsfihdif]***

[***Photo example***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFaJS.png)

Here is my errorControler:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CustomErrorController.class);


@RequestMapping("/error")
public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            //404 with the wrong URI entered by user

            log.error("[NOT FOUND 404] User [" + auth.getName() + "] tried to access this URL : ["+ request.getRequestURL() +"] : [" + request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER) + "]";

            return "errors/404";

        } else {
            //something else
            return "errors/error";
        }
    }
    return "error";
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/error";
}
}
```

Here is the output:

> **2018-06-22 18:48:59.507 ERROR
>               [nio-9090-exec-7] c.b.g.c.CustomErrorController
>
>               MSG ==> [NOT FOUND 404] User [dumi7ru] tried to access this URL  : [http://localhost:9090/error] : [null]**

Comment: And what is your question? What is the most probable reason for it to be null? Have you read the javadoc? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-

Comment: @JB Nizet i want to obtain the Uri like i mentioned in my example.How can i do this? Thank you

Comment: The way you did. Just don't expect every request to have such a header. Sometimes, there just isn't one because people go directly to a URL. Sometimes there isn't one because people don't want to tell you where they come from (for very good privacy reasons). Sometimes they could be removed by proxies.

Comment: @JB Nizet, i think i did not ask the question correctly... So i don't need to know where they are coming from, i need the URL they are going to... how you mentioned   _**people go directly to a URL**_ , so i need this URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then don't get the referrer URL from the request. Get the URL of the request. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI--

Comment: I tried before and i'm getting /path from @RequestMapping method. I added the output upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get original URI as

```
String originalUri = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
```

Similar query on stack  [web.xml 404 redirect to servlet, how to get the original URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465906/web-xml-404-redirect-to-servlet-how-to-get-the-original-uri)