# How to get requested url in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        Object url = request.getRequestURL()
        model.addAttribute("url", url)
        return "404";
    }

}
```

However, the above url always gives me the url "/error", even if the user has went to the page "http://mywebsite.com/does-not-exist". How would I retrieve the url as entered in by the user before generating the error page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pull it from request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)

This thread has further information : [web.xml 404 redirect to servlet, how to get the original URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7465906/5126865)